# What ports are open on xbox? Will it respond to pings/TCP connection?

Tags: c#, networking, telnet, wireshark, xbox360

I'm trying to write an application to shut down my pc when I shutdown my xbox. The issue I'm having is my xbox dosent seem to respond to pings.

I downloaded a port scanning tool and that didn't find any open ports on it. So I put up wireshark and ran a trace while streaming media to it. I can see TCP traffic travelling initially on 6453 then as "complex-link" on various other ports. I cant connect on telnet to 6453 or the other few I tried.

Any advice on how to progress? I'm not sure if the xbox even listens on any ports or how I find out if it does. Possibly there is a more elegant way of doing what I want? (I'm intending to use C# for the actual application)

Comment: Those who are voting to close, how is "I'm trying to write an application" off topic here. *facepalm*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly common security practice to not listen to pings. It can be considered a security risk.

I don't think there's a reliable way to do what you want. The Xbox is going to only open ports when it wants to go out and contact other boxes. It's probably not going to sit there and leave ports open.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and acurate reply! Im thinking ill probably just monitor network traffic and shutdown if there isnt anything being transfered. Its not ideal but it should work.